# question about Juju charm & bundles

Tags: juju

I've a doubt, the charm or the bundles created on release previously the 16.04 can be used on newest release of Ubuntu? or I've to use them only for 
that specific release?

an example is that

[image]

I can deploy it on node with Ubuntu 16.04- 16.10? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, each charm is created on that particular release and it can't be deployed on upper release of Ubuntu.